# cxGrid prevent grouped delete

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe4, tcxgrid

In my cxGrid I have records grouped by date. However, when a user selects a grouped date and hits delete all the records that were filed under that date get deleted. Is there a way to prevent this ? I would like the records to be deleted individually.

EDIT: I forgot to mention: I am grouping using GroupByBox function of the grid.

Comment: Where is your code? Are you using the grid in bound or unbound mode?

Comment: bound mode of course ...

Comment: If user selected group and pressed Del, it actually means that he is trying to delete the group (all items). Anyway, if you are not happy with default behavior, you can disable Delete command for grid (see .OptionData of view) and implement it as you want - for example assign action to some toolbar item and delete what you want.

Comment: so that means I can not actually prevent the group deletion ? Any way I can detect group selection for deletion so I can warn user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `gridView.Controller.FocusedRow.IsData` property before delete action. Here is example:

1. Disable "auto deleting" feature by set `gridView.OptionsData.Deleting = False;`
2. Add code in gridView's event `OnKeyUp`:

   ```pascal
   procedure TmyForm.gridViewKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
   begin
     if (Key = VK_DELETE) and (gridView.Controller.FocusedRow <> nil) then
     begin
       if gridView.Controller.FocusedRow.IsData then
       begin
         gridView.DataController.DeleteFocused;
       end
       else
       begin
         ShowMessage('You can''t delete group records.');
       end;
     end;
   end;
   ```

If you use default dataset actions or `cxDBNavigator` try this:

1. Disable "confirm delete" feature by set `gridView.OptionsData.DeleteConfirmation = False;`
2. Add "abort" code in dataset event `BeforeDelete`:

   ```pascal
   procedure TmyForm.DataSetBeforeDelete(DataSet: TDataSet);
   begin
     if (gridView.Controller.FocusedRow <> nil)
       and not gridView.Controller.FocusedRow.IsData then
     begin
       ShowMessage('You can''t delete group records.');
       Abort;
     end;
   end;
   ```
3. Add "abort" code to code navigator event `OnButtonClick` (if you don't want to show delete confirmation):

   ```pascal
   procedure TmyForm.DBNavigatorButtonsButtonClick(Sender: TObject; AButtonIndex: Integer; var ADone: Boolean);
   begin
     if (AButtonIndex = NBDI_DELETE)
       and (gridView.Controller.FocusedRow <> nil)
       and not gridView.Controller.FocusedRow.IsData then
     begin
       ShowMessage('You can''t delete group records.');
       Abort;
     end;
   end;
   ```

Comment: that is very nice but I need to retain the option of deleting records in the grid.

Comment: problem with this is that I am using the built in navigator of the grid. If I prevent deletion then user must use keyboard to delete the record because the delete glyph is grayed out.

Comment: I'm added tips for dataset and date navigator's code. Read second part of answer.

Comment: [dcc32 Error] DataModule.pas(179): E2029 ')' expected but identifier 'Controller' found ----[dcc32 Error] DataModule.pas(179): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'cxGrid1DBTableView1'---This is using your second suggestion...

Comment: You must add uses clause with form's unit (it must contain grid) to DataModule.pas like: "uses unit1"

Comment: And use code like that: form1.cxGrid1DBTableView1.Controller.FocusedRow